# DateTime Display in Windows Form application

Tags: winforms, datetime-format, datetimeformatinfo

I have a windows form application. I have a query which return me datetime in the format dd-MM-yyyy.
But when this datetime is displayed in a datagrid it is displayed as `dd/MM/yyyy`.
I wish to display `dd-MM-yyyy` in my datagrid. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set this in the column's DefaultCellStyle.Format:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```